# Problema con botones en Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, botón

Básicamente estoy haciendo un programa que me mande un saludo en la consola de esta forma "Hola " + el nombre que ponga en la etiqueta entry. Y además que el label al apretar el boton cambie a la palabra Julio. Lo estoy implementando de esta manera pero al iniciar el programa se ejecuta el metodo sin yo apretar el botón, les dejo mi código

```
import tkinter as tk


class Practica1(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.geometry('600x200')
        self.lbl = tk.Label(self.window, text = "Nombre")
        self.lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.txt = tk.Entry(self.window)
        self.txt.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
        self.btn = tk.Button(self.window, text="Pulsame", command= self.clickme())
        self.btn.grid(column=0, row = 2)    
        self.window.mainloop()
    def clickme(self):

        mensaje = "Hola " + self.txt.get()
        print(mensaje)
        self.lbl.configure(text="Julio")
```

Comment: Muestra tu codigo como texto.

Comment: Listo! Ya acabo de editarlo

Comment: Typo, cambia a `..., command=self.clickme)`

Comment: Muchas gracias @eyllanesc! Se resolvió!

Answer (score 1):

El parámetro `command` de un botón debe recibir como valor **una función**, pero tú le asignabas *el valor devuelto por la función*.

### Explicación más detallada

En python las funciones se pueden asignar a variables. Por ejemplo imagina que tenemos esta función:

```
def saludar():
    print("Hola")
```

Una vez definida, el símbolo `saludar` representa a esa función, por lo que podríamos asignarlo a una variable así:

```
a = saludar
```

y entonces `a` sería otro símbolo que se refiere a la misma función, con lo que si más adelante haces `a()`, ejecutas la función.

Si, en cambio, hubiéramos hecho:

```
a = saludar()
```

entonces se habría ejecutado la función en ese punto, y lo que recibe `a` es el valor retornado por la función (que en este caso sería `None` porque la función no contiene `return` explícito para retornar otra cosa).

Las funciones también se pueden pasar como parámetros. Por ejemplo, la siguiente función sirve para ejecutar otra, que reciba como paráemtro:

```
def ejecuta(funcion_a_ejecutar):
    print("Voy a ejecutar la función")
    funcion_a_ejecutar()
```

Si la llamamos así:

```
ejecuta(saludar)
```

le estamos pasando como parámetro el símbolo `saludar`. Dentro de `ejecuta`, el nombre `funcion_a_ejecutar` es por tanto equivalente a `saludar`, y cuando invocamos `funcion_a_ejecutar()` estaremos invocando `saludar()`.

Si en cambio hubiéramos hecho:

```
ejecuta(saludar())
```

python ejecutará `saludar()` antes de invocar `ejecuta()`, y le pasará a `ejecuta()` el valor retornado por `saludar()`, que ya dijimos que era  `None`. Dentro de `ejecuta()` ahora el símbolo `funcion_a_ejecutar` tendrá el valor `None`, y cuando hagamos `funcion_a_ejecutar()` estaríamos intentando "ejecutar None", lo que producirá una excepción porque `None` no es ejecutable.

En tu caso ha ocurrido lo mismo. El botón necesita que le pases qué función hay que ejecutar cuando se pulse, lo que equivale al paso de función como parámetro que acabamos de ver. Al haber usado tú `self.clickme()` estás ejecutando `clickme()` en ese punto y pasándole el valor retornado. Tienes que pasarle `self.clickme`.